# Why is not "9007199254740991" treated as an integer index?

Tags: javascript, specifications

According to [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object-type), a string-valued property key whose numeric value is `2 ** 53 - 1` must be treated as an integer index.
According to [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), the `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` internal method must enumerate property keys which is an integer index, in ascending numeric order.
According to [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-reflect.ownkeys), `Reflect.ownKeys` calls the `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` internal method.

So, the following code should show property keys in ascending numeric order (i.e., `["9007199254740990", "9007199254740991"]`) if my understanding is correct.
However, all the existing implementations show property keys in ascending chronological order of property creation (i.e., `["9007199254740991", "9007199254740990"]`).

```js
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys({"9007199254740991": null, "9007199254740990": null}));
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: As far as I understand, as stated in `OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys`, which is returned by `OwnPropertyKeys`, each key is added as last element. So you got exactly the same order that you are providing as input..

Comment: @Yuri If so, why does `Reflect.ownKeys({"1": null, "0": null})` return `["0", "1"]`?

Comment: I am getting `[  "9007199254740991",  "9007199254740990"]` in my console

Comment: Can I ask what browser you are using @anqooqie?

Comment: What is your question? why does `Reflect.ownKeys({"1": null, "0": null})` return `["0", "1"]`? OR Why is not “9007199254740991” treated as an integer index?

Comment: @RensvWalstijn The latter.

Comment: @RensvWalstijn My browser is Chrome 64.0.3282.186.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The specification of the `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` internal method in ECMAScript 2017](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) (and [in 2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys)) did not match the real behavior of all major JavaScript engines, so in ECMAScript 2019, [the specification has been fixed](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys).
See [the discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1242).

Answer (score 1):

`9007199254740991` is the maximum safe integer in JavaScript.

```js
var x = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1,
  y = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2,
  z = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 3,
  i = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 4,
  j = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 5;

console.log("max: "+Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
// expected output: 9007199254740991
// real output:     9007199254740991

console.log("x:   "+x);
// expected output: 9007199254740992
// real output:     9007199254740992

console.log("y:   "+y);
// expected output: 9007199254740993
// real output:     9007199254740992

console.log("z:   "+z);
// expected output: 9007199254740994
// real output:     9007199254740994

console.log("i:   "+i);
// expected output: 9007199254740995
// real output:     9007199254740996

console.log("j:   "+j);
// expected output: 9007199254740996
// real output:     9007199254740996
```

And some acts like expected.

Read on the following:

1. [MDN web docs > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
2. [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

So what we know:

> bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or 2147483647.

What I do not know is how the `Reflect.ownKeys()` sorts the indexes to numeric order.
Because of the following snippet:

```js
const objs = [
    // does not work
    {
        9007199254740991: null,
        9007199254740990: null,
    },
    // works
    {
        2147483648: null,
        // max save bitwise number
        2147483647: null,
    },
    // works
    {
        4294967295: null,
        // max save bitwise number times 2
        4294967294: null,
    },
    // does not work
    {
        5368709118: null,
        // max save bitwise number times 2.5
        5368709117: null,
    }
];

const objkeys = [],
    max = objs.length;

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    objkeys.push(Reflect.ownKeys(objs[i]))
}

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(objkeys[i][0]+" < "+objkeys[i][1]);
}
```

I hoped you learned something about 9007199254740991 and JavaScript

Comment: My question is not why `Reflect.ownKeys` returns string values.
According to the specification, each of `"9007199254740991"` and `"9007199254740990"` should be treated as an integer index, so `Reflect.ownKeys({"9007199254740991": null, "9007199254740990": null})` should return property keys in ascending numeric order, but the reality is not the case, why?

Comment: @anqooqie Sorry for misunderstanding, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @anqooqie I edited the answer. I hope it is clear for you.